# Can't save the illustration .278 on mac (m1)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Recently downloaded illustrator, had some artwork, and am trying to save the file now (either as .ai or as .svg), but in both cases I receive the message:

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: Sorry, technical support is off topic. Try Adobe.

Comment: See [Illustrator support for networks and removable media](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/kb/illustrator-support-networks-removable-media.html)

Comment: Jup, it was 100% that - it was on a network drive that I tried to save. When doing locally works perfect. I was worried it was related to the m1 chip

Comment: Specifically working with Adobe software it's not a good idea working directly from a server (as is evident). Well... unless it's a Dropbox style implementation where you are actually working with local files, it's just uploading them online in the background. That said it's only a good idea you're the only person touching the files... and you don't have any bandwidth caps :) ...or the syncing is happening in the local network.